# I close in all around you, making you nervous. What am I?

Tags: riddle

I close in all around you, making you nervous. You want to evade me as much as possible. Lifts, Tunnels, and under your bed.

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> Darkness.

Reasoning:

> Darkness can make people nervous and with poor lighting is all around everyone.

> People want to evade darkness.

> In lifts, in tunnels, and under one's bed, darkness resides.

Comment: This is the correct answer!